# logn function in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to use logn function in Jmeter? Is it any addition addon required to use it? Is there any other option available in Jmeter to do the same operation?

I am trying to extract the Output from the response and assigning it to a variable,
Please any one help me..

Answer (score 0):

[logn](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn) - is this what you're looking for ? The input needs to be a string for logn ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to extract the Output from the output from the response and assign to a variable, you want to use Regular Expression Extractor:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor